# Qt Designer can't reference ApplicationWindow size

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, designer

This is my first post here in stackoverflow so I'm having a hard time even explaining the issue.

I started to develop a UI for my App in Qt Designer and the Creator.
With concerns for Scalability I design all my app pages to parent the **ApplicationWindow widgth and height**.

This works fine when the app is build but in the Qt Designer the pages have 0 size. 
So I can't work with them in the Designer.

Is it possible to circumvent that?

here is a code example:

**main.qml**

```
ApplicationWindow {
        id: main_window
        visible: true
        width: 450
        height: 700
        minimumWidth: 450
        minimumHeight: 700
```

Page1.Form.ui.qml

```
Page {
    id: p_basicpage
    width: ApplicationWindow.width
    height: ApplicationWindow.height
```

When the app is built it works fine specially with regards to Scalability.
The problem is with the designer:

[image]

Comment: The way you reference main window property is wrong. You should reference it by `id` so it should be replaced with `width: main_window.width`. But I advice you to use anchors instead: `anchors.fill: parent`

Comment: Hi and thanks for the tip. I tried `width: main_window.width` but the issue is the same. Pages can't have `anchors.fill: parent` proprieties :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Page`'s do have the `anchor.fill` property, set it from the *Text Editor* (not from the `Form Editor`) and get rid of `width` and `height` properties:

```
Page {
   id: p_basicpage
   anchors.fill: parent
```

Comment: I highly recommend you not to use QML Designer, at least while you are learning QML.

Comment: Could you clarify this a bit more. So should I only use the Designer when I'm a pro at QML? That's not very encouraging.